# Can't q.get() with multiprocess threading and queue

Tags: python

I am unable to get this code to work. I keep getting a 'str' object has no attribute 'get'. I have a text file on my desktop called SDS.txt which has in it a bunch of hostnames. I am trying to use multiprocess threads and queues to ping the list (around 150 PCs) with 4 different threads simultaneously.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from queue import Queue
import time
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='conversion.log', format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(thread)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('Conversion')
pathDesktop = "C:\\users\\example\\desktop\\SDS.txt"
q = Queue()


def Conversion(q):
  for path in q.get():
    response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + path)   
    if response == 0:
      logger.info(path + " is being changed.")
      print(path + " is being changed.")
    else:
      logger.error(path + " is down.")
      print(path + " is down.")

 if __name__ == '__main__':
  start = time.time()
  with open(pathDesktop,'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    f.close()
    for path in contents.splitlines():
      path = path.strip()
      q.put(path)        
  pool = ThreadPool(4)
  results = pool.map(Conversion, q.queue)
  print("Entire job took: ",time.time()-start, " seconds")
```

Comment: Your `Queue` reads `q`, change `.map(SDSConversion, q.queue)` to `.map(SDSConversion, q)`

Comment: I get an error then saying 'Queue' object is not iterable

Comment: `for path in q.get()` returns just one path.  You need to make a loop in your thread that gets single items from the queue.  Also your code example is not complete: You have `SDSConversion` but the only function you have defined is called just `Conversion`.  Please try to narrow down your problem to a [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use a Queue when the pool has one built in. Just:

```
results = pool.map(Conversion, (path.strip() for path in contents.splitlines()))
```

And:

```
def Conversion(path):
    return result
```

You only need to use a Queue if you are using raw threads or processes and not a worker pool.

If this causes a problem, like

```
from itertools import count
def func(x): return x
for result in pool.imap(func, count()):
    print x
```

does. Complain. This should run in near constant memory. But internally the pool has two unsynchronized threads one that enqueues jobs and the other that dequeues results. The first can run ahead of the second resulting in the queue growing without limit.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't iterate over a Queue. Instead, you need to manually call Queue.get() each time. A simple recipe might look like:

```py
while not q.empty():
    obj = q.get()
    # do_stuff....
```

2. You shouldn't `close` a file you manually opened with a `with` statement. The `with` statement does that for you.
3. When using a Pool, there's no need to create and handle your own Queues. You can use the map method with a function and an iterable to automatically distribute the objects accordingly.

Note that the output is going to be extremely garbled because all the processes will be trying to print at the same time. There's probably a way around this, but that's not part of the question.

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
from queue import Queue
import time
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='conversion.log', format = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(thread)d - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('Conversion')

pathDesktop = "C:\\users\\example\\desktop\\SDS.txt"
q = Queue()


def Conversion(path):
  response = os.system("ping -n 1 " + path)   
  if response == 0:
    logger.info(path + " is being changed.")
    print(path + " is being changed.")
  else:
    logger.error(path + " is down.")
    print(path + " is down.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  start = time.time()
  inputs = []
  with open(pathDesktop,'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    for path in contents.splitlines():
      path = path.strip()
      inputs.append(path)
  with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
    results = pool.map(Conversion, inputs)
  print("Entire job took: ",time.time()-start, " seconds")
```